# from 2bit branch predictor to 8-bit predictor

Tags: c, architecture, parallel-processing

I got an project to convert 2-bit branch predictor in 'SimpleScalar' to 8-bit branch predictor. Which means I need to change the source code of 2-bit predicor from 'SimpleScalar' and make it work like a 8-bit predictor.

I know how predictors work but I do not know how to implement a branch predictor using c language. Recommend me some implementation of 8-bit brach predictor.

Comment: Your instructor hasn't covered branch predictors a little bit in class?

Comment: Yes he did. I know the basics. What is branch predictor and how it works. But the problem is I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Do you know how to implement a 2-bit predictor? (I have some trouble with the idea that you know how it works but don't know how to implement one)

Comment: I mean to say I know the theoretical way. I know how it works, but I have never implemented myself. I so wrote don't know how  to implement.

Comment: Must be time to read some technical documents.  (Welcome to school). The chip design business is full of people trying to design better branch predictors. Most of those papers refer to earlier ones, and some of them will surely refer to implementations of 2 bit detectors and various generalizations. And of course, Wikipedia has a nice intro to branch predictors. You didn't find that with Google?

Comment: Yes I did and I have already read the Wikipedia description. As I told earlier also, I am looking some documents which can give me idea about how to implement the predictor.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement a two-level adaptive branch predictor with an 8-bit shift register that holds the branching history and its value is used to index a table of 256 2-bit predictors. Read about shift registers and add the indexing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This set of slides](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/csep548/06au/lectures/branchPred.pdf) does a good job of describing 2-bit branch prediction.  Extending this to 8-bit (I assume) means that we are allowed a state machine of 256 states rather then 4 in the 2 bit case to decide what is going on.  If we extend the 4 state case in the logical way, there will be 128 states where we predict the branch will be taken and 128 where it's not taken...a kind of hysteresis.

I am supposing you are programming inside a processor emulator or simulator.  You didn't say.  The C code only has to keep track of the last 128 decisions made and only switch to the alternate prediction if 128 guesses were wrong:

```
static int stickiness = 128;          // assume 128 states of knowledge that the default branch will occur
static int predicted_branch = 1;      // default prediction is (say) branch taken

if (simulated_branch_condition_is_true != predicted_branch) {
  if (--stickiness <= 0) {
    predicted_branch = simulated_branch_condition_is_true;
    stickiness = 128;
  }
}
// Now simulate the predicted_branch. If it's wrong, we will later simulate a pipeline, flush etc.
```

Without more information, this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken your "2-bit branch predictor" in SimpleScalar in an implementation of [Two-level adaptive predictor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) , now I'm not sure if I understand what you mean with "8-bit brach predictor" anyway, The neural branch predictor concept is very promising. Most of the state of the art branch predictors are using a perceptron predictor. you might find it useful to take a look to an implementation in C language based on [Dynamic Branch Prediction with Perceptrons](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lin/papers/hpca01.pdf) that is available as source code on https://github.com/sumitdhoble/Branch-Prediction